# css font icon shows char

Tags: css, reactjs, font-face, next.js

I'm working on a React project which uses next.js for SSR. I have no problem with fontawesome but when I create an Icomoon font icon, icons not showing and it shows characters. font icons work on another simple HTML but on this website it has problem. here is how it's showing fonts.

[image: character instead of icon]

in this picture, B should be an icon.

so what is the problem? the website is in Spanish language and uses Latin characters.